# How to make 100 divided by 110 equal a decimal in Java / Android

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to use the follow code to produce a decimal number, but the evaluation of l divided by h (low by high) always comes out to be 0.

How can I correct this? Thanks!

```
EditText marketValLow = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.marketValLow);
            EditText marketValHigh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.marketValHigh);
            String valLow = marketValLow.getText().toString();
            String valHigh = marketValHigh.getText().toString();
            int l = Integer.parseInt(valLow);
            int h = Integer.parseInt(valHigh);

            if (valLow.trim().equals("") || valHigh.trim().equals("")) {

                Toast.makeText(CurrentMarketValue.this, "You need to enter a high AND low." + valLowIndex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if ((l / h) < .9) { 

                Toast.makeText(CurrentMarketValue.this, "The range between your value cannot be more than 10%." + (l / h), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

Comment: Btw, the topic and the code dont match. In the code you have a ratio of 9/10, in the topic you have a ratio of 100/110 or 10/11, which is close, but not the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(int / int) will result in a int.

Instead do: `double result = ((double)l) / ((double) h);` and instead of checking on `(l / h)` do a check on `result` instead.

Comment: It is fair more complicated than needed but it is clear what it is doing.

Answer (score 4):

```
double val = ((double)l)/h
```

Answer (score 4):

You're doing [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html). Force one of the operands of / to be a double.

```
((double)l / h)
```

Answer (score 2):

it is a basic part of many type languages. Integer division shows the results of whole divisions. In your case you could make it 1.0 / h or typecast one of the numbers to float or double.

Answer (score 2):

Just by way of contrast to all the other answers:

```
if ((l * 10) < (h * 9))
```

Not saying its better (in fact if l or h has the possibility of being greater than about 200 million it's bad), just different.

Comment: Worse is still worse. THat will not produce the desired result, to start with.

Comment: Ditto, this appears correct to me. However, the original condition is (I suppose) much closer to the business logic, which would make it superior by virtue of being clearer.

Comment: It has to be said that if I were doing this in a production situation I would use the same solution as everybody else.  The main reason is that (as TomTom demonstrates) my answer obfuscates what you are trying to do.  @TomTom: divide both sides of the inequality by 10 and h and see what you get.

Comment: I would have written if (l * 10 < h * 9) in any case. The * always comes before < .

Answer (score 1):

It would appea ryou're using an integer where a float or double would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I think JeremyP is right. TomTom why do you say it's wrong?
The following are all equivalent, by properties of inequalities (multiplying both sides by the same positive amount... assuming h >= 0):

```
(l / h) < .9
l < (.9 * h)
(l * 10) < (h * 9)
```

The latter also has the nice property of not throwing an exception when h = 0.

Comment: You need to cast l to double anyway, so you won't get an exception dividing by 0.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, can you elaborate on that? I don't understand. Casting `l` to double will avoid an exception when dividing `l` by 0?

Comment: int l = 5; System.out.println((double) l / 0); doesn't produce an exception.

Comment: Peter, good point, thanks for the reminder. It produces double.NaN. And what does (NaN < .9) evaluate to? I'm assuming False, which would work out ok in the above code.